# Invalidate without OnPaint

Tags: c#, winforms, animation, graphics, invalidation

I'm trying to make an animation in Win Forms, and I have tried a different approach than calling Invalidate() in the timer_elapsed handler and then doing things in the OnPaintHandler.

I just directly draw an image on a pictureBox, then when the timer_ticks, I call Invalidate, and then I manually redraw the image on updated position.

```
static void tmrMoving_Elapsed(object sender, EventArgs e, Train t)
{
    MainForm.playBox.Invalidate();

    g.DrawImage(t.components[i], new Rectangle(
                new Point(t.nextVagoonPositionX * 20, t.nextVagoonPositionY * 20), 
                new Size(20, 20)));
    t.nextVagoonPositionX += 1;
    t.nextPositionX = -1;
}
```

I have a problem, that when the timer ticks, the desired image sometimes get drawn, and sometimes not, like 30% chance to not draw(I have 1sec timer intervals so I can see it), even if the object is moving or just being in the same location.

Things I have tried:

1.Setting a region in Invalidate() args -> the image got drawn many times next to the older images (So it wasn't repaint at the desired location as the old images remained in their locations)

2.Calling Update() or Refresh() or both after the invalidate-> No image was ever shown

3.Combining Update() or Refresh() or both with Invalidate(rectangulous region) -> no image ever shown

4.Setting DoubleBuffering true -> no effect

5.Fiddling with this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true); -> no effect (not even sure what it does btw.)

Comment: It does get drawn, it just doesn't last very long.  Overpainted by playBox' normal OnPaintBackground and OnPaint methods.  Whether you can see at all depends on how often you blink your eyes and how responsive the UI thread is.  The ultimate example of a threading race bug, one you can actually see and don't have to wait a week for.  You'll have to stop doing it wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not supposed to directly paint UI controls outside of the OnPaint handler. In "lower level" WinAPI, you'd only painting to the screen on WM_PAINT, which is what raises the OnPaint event.

Move your drawing code (`g.DrawImage(...)`) out of the timer handler and into the `OnPaint` handler.

Comment: Thank you for info, may I ask who is the sender when the OnPaint is handled? Is it that timer?

Comment: No, it's best though of as the windows system itself. For all purposes, that happens "behind the scenes".

Comment: The sender is the PictureBox, the cause is the system or your code